# How can I send an Android app that I'm developing to someone over e-mail?

Tags: android, email-attachments

This is my first Android app. I need to email what I have so far to someone for testing.

How should I do I export the app and attach it, so it is not being treated as Junk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse run the app on the emulator to test it. Now Eclipse should have created a bin folder in your project folder. In this folder you will find an apk file that contains your app.

Just send this file to your friend via email. He know can install the file on the emulator if he has one running. If not he can just plugin his phone via usb move the file to the SD-Card remove the USB connection and then navigate to the file on his SD-Card with a file browser like [ASTRO](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-metago-astro-qzq.aspx) and select the, item now the application manager should show up and he can install the app. If this does not work he has to go to settings -> applications -> and enable unknown sources.

Comment: If the receiver uses gmail it is not possible, since gmail (and many other providers) sort out emails with an APK attached, even if it is in an (even encrypted) Zip Archive.

Answer (score 11):

Much simpler method:

1. Put the apk on your web server
2. Create a QR Barcode image using:
   http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chld=H|1&chl=http://myserver/myapp.apk
3. Then send him that barcode in an email and tell him to scan it using the barcode reader app.

The barcode reader app will see the barcode and provide a hyperlink for the user to click. They click the link and the app downloads and installs.

Comment: So how would one create a QR barcode with that link you shared?

Comment: If you look at the link, you see how: just add the url you want to link to at the end of the URL: `chl=http://myserver/myapp.apk`

Answer (score 9):

compile/build your app, it should produce a file like `myAppName.apk`, just send it via email to your friend

try to look in `yourProjectPath/bin` folder

Comment: If the receiver uses gmail it is not possible, since gmail (and many other providers) sort out emails with an APK attached, even if it is in an (even encrypted) Zip Archive. How do you send it, without the email being treated as Junk by most providers?

Comment: While this answer could have worked in 2010, today it is pretty much impossible. Most email providers now force scan for apks and zipped files and block them. Even encrypted files fall victim.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are using Android Studio for application development.

Follow these steps:

Go to "build" from the navigation bar in Android Studio.

Go to "build bundle(s)/APK(s)" from the drop down that appears.

Click on "build APK(s)". You will get a notification box at the bottom right of your screen.

Click on "locate". Two files will appear. One is a ".json" file and one is an ".apk" file.

Send these files to your friends on WhatsApp and tell them to download the JSON file and install the APK file. Now your application is running.

You are done.

Answer (score 5):

You can also **right-click on your project** (in eclipse) and click on **export**
then select "**Export Android Application**" and give all the details...
after you finish you will have a myAppName.apk, which you can email

Comment: If the receiver uses gmail it is not possible, since gmail (and many other providers) sort out emails with an APK attached, even if it is in an (even encrypted) Zip Archive. How do you send it, without the email being treated as Junk by most providers?

Comment: You can use the Microsoft [App Center][1] to build and distribute your Signed/Unsigned APK with your beta testers.

Or you can also use Google Drive, DropBox, Amazon S3 to distribute your APK


  [1]: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-center/

Comment: This is false. I've tried using those services, aside from DropBox (which is insecure as hell) and none of them worked. Perhaps some app apks get past the filters, but anything I've tried of size or that connects to other servers will get flagged and be inaccessible, often without an error message.

Answer (score 5):

**Export Android Application** would be the correct way to generate the apk. Using the one that eclipse uses has debugging info, plus it is signed with debug key, not an actual key. If you install an application signed with one key, and then later try to install an application (same package name) with a different key, you will first have to uninstall the original application first.

Comment: But how do you send it, without the email being treated as Junk by most providers?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio build with "build"->"Build Bundle"->"Build APKs" which you'll find in the folder `app/build/outputs/apk/debug` then.

You cannot attach the file in your email directly, since APKs are treated as **junk** by most email providers. So upload the apk somewhere and send the link to your co-worker.

If a link is not enough, with a simple trick, you can send the file anyway:

1. Rename the file: attach `.bin` at the end of the filename (i.e. myApp.apk.bin)
2. send the fake `.bin` file
3. Tell the receiver, that they have to rename it to plain `.apk` before installing. (On android renaming is possible with a file-manager, i.e. like Totalcommander)

Comment: Nice trick. I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Android Studio for application development**
[image: Step1:Clean Your Project.]
[image: Step2:build apk]
[image: Step3][image: Rename apk file.It is not mandatory but would be meaningful.]

***now your apk is ready to share. Go to email and attach the apk file and enjoy.[note:Maximum Email Size Limits maybe 25MB]***

Comment: Most apps cannot be sent via GMail due to size restrictions and/or virus detection false positives. Other services can sometimes be less restrictive, but this is an issue on most I've tried.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is it is very simple, Droid devices understand what an APK is.  So, tell your friend to Check "Enable Unknown Sources" currently in Settings->Security (not Settings-> Applications as of now.) Then email them the APK.  Upon receiving it, Droid will either get it installed, or they can download it to downloads, where they can also install it from.  Accept the Permissions, and off you go.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Microsoft [App Center](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-center/) to build and distribute your Signed/Unsigned APK with your beta testers.

**Or** you can also use Google Drive, DropBox, Amazon S3 to distribute your APK