# Sending Android app to friend

Tags: android

Hey, this might be simple but I dunno how to go about it.  I have an app that I'm working on, and I'd like my friend to take a look at it.  How can I go about sending them the apk package so they can play with the app?

Comment: You can send it via Fedex. But, I'd better rather try sending it via email.

Comment: Already answered, quite thoroughly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068848/how-can-i-send-an-android-app-that-im-developing-to-someone-over-e-mail/3070833#3070833

Answer (score 2):

You can send it as an email attachment, for instance. The process for installing it is the same as if you get the app from a source other than Market, and is documented in many places. [This is the first hit](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/37151.aspx) that I got on Google.

You can find the `.APK` file in the bin directory of the Eclipse project. Also, keep in mind that if you don't sign your application with a valid certificate your friend will have to explicitly enable the 'install third party applications'; otherwise the SO won't let you install it.

Comment: When I build the application from Eclipse, is the apk file stored on my computer in the folder where all the source code is?

Answer (score 0):

Send it to them and use appsinstaller (available from the market) if android os  < 2.2. Or onymous (cant remember the spelling, but a market search of installer pulls it up) if using android os 2.2 +.

From my experience, I am unable to save email attachments (if sending the apk via email and using the default email app). Otherwise, they could use their browser and download the attachment and use the programs above to install it.